# session not working between pages of different directories

Tags: php, apache, session

I had been working on this issue since last two days, but still unable to solve.

i had two script one in root directory where session registered and remain persistent when i access the page again, but when i am going to access the page from sub directory script suggest that no session is registered.

detail explanation below :

Problem is that when i start_session() from root directory script
that is  : http://www.kstreethome.com/test.php it's working fine

Code for /test.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "This is session save path : " . session_save_path() . "</br>";
//echo phpinfo();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['User']))
    {
        echo "Session not set </br>";
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['User'] = "Hiren";
                    $_SESSION['AccessType'] = "U";
                    $_SESSION['UserType'] = "W";
                    $_SESSION['UserID'] = "123";
                    $_SESSION['DataUser'] = "Test";
                    $_SESSION['Password'] = "Test";

        echo session_id();

        echo $_SESSION['User'];
        echo $_SESSION['AccessType'];
        echo $_SESSION['UserType'];
        echo $_SESSION['UserID'];
        echo $_SESSION['DataUser'];
        echo $_SESSION['Password'];     
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Session set </br>";

            echo $_SESSION['User'];
        echo $_SESSION['AccessType'];
        echo $_SESSION['UserType'];
        echo $_SESSION['UserID'];
        echo $_SESSION['DataUser'];
        echo $_SESSION['Password']; 



    }


?>
```

but

when i start_session() from sub directory Ajax script
that is  : http://www.kstreethome.com/Ajax/test.php it's not working however in this script it is storing session and accessible in the same run but when i reload /Ajax/test.php the session is just destroyed and i have to start again.

Code for /Ajax/test.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "This is session save path : " . session_save_path() . "</br>";
//echo phpinfo();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['User']))
    {
        echo "Session not set </br>";
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['User'] = "Hiren";
                    $_SESSION['AccessType'] = "U";
                    $_SESSION['UserType'] = "W";
                    $_SESSION['UserID'] = "123";
                    $_SESSION['DataUser'] = "Test";
                    $_SESSION['Password'] = "Test";

        echo session_id();

        echo $_SESSION['User'];
        echo $_SESSION['AccessType'];
        echo $_SESSION['UserType'];
        echo $_SESSION['UserID'];
        echo $_SESSION['DataUser'];
        echo $_SESSION['Password'];     
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Session set </br>";

            echo $_SESSION['User'];
        echo $_SESSION['AccessType'];
        echo $_SESSION['UserType'];
        echo $_SESSION['UserID'];
        echo $_SESSION['DataUser'];
        echo $_SESSION['Password']; 



    }


?>
```

the code is same in both file and it's for testing purpose

another strange thing is that in root script /test.php it says session path '' that is default null as i had not changed defaults inn php.ini, but in the script /Ajax/test.php it says session save path is /tmp strange right?

it is needless to say it works fine  my local server but not on hosting server
so please guide me in this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put `session_start()` at top of every page

```
<?php
 session_start();
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 2):

before going to use you need to start seassion

```
 <?php 
 session_start();
 // your code
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call session_start() before any access to $_SESSION. Place it at the top of each script and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

always start code with `session_start()`

```
<?php
 session_start();
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 1):

User `<?php session_start()` in first line before any session value get or set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `session_start()` before using $_SESSION, but I would really recommend making a wrapper class to handle all this for you so you don't have a bunch of clutter.

```
$session = new Session();
$session->set('key', 'val');
```